# Reconfiguring (or resetting) singleton services in Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have a legacy code that I decided to refactor using Google Guice.

In my project, I have a service called `AccessVerifier` which looks like this:

```
@Singleton
public class AccessVerifier {
    
    private JWTVerifier verifier;

    public AccessVerifier(String secret) {
        this.verifier = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC256(secret)).build();
    }

    public void setSecret(String secret){
        this.verifier = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC256(secret)).build();
    }

    public DecodedJWT decodeToken(String token)
    {
        DecodedJWT jwt = this.verifier.verify(token);

        // Verify some claims from the obtained token

        return jwt;
    }
}
```

From time to time, we rotate that `secret` parameter. I want to be able to "reconfigure", or reset the service so it reinitializes that `verifier` member.

Without Guice, we had a classic Singleton implementation(via `getInstance()`), so I would do something like:

```
AccessVerifier.getInstance().setSecret(...);
```

But since migrating to Guice that is no longer possible since, naturally, I want Guice to manage my service instances.

I ***could*** do something like:

```
App.getInjector().get(AccessVerifier.class).setSecret(...)
```

But this, whoa, feels incredibly dirty :(

Another idea I had is to pass `Provider<String>` to `AccessVerifier`, but I don't want to create `JWTVerifier` each and every time. I would need to store the "previous" secret and compare it every time I want to use the `verifier`.

Is there any other way of achieving this?

Comment: the code you posted won't even compile (for several reasons). Also, I fail to see what it has to do with a singleton?

Comment: Yes, the code was copied/pasted so I generally missed some lines (and potentially made some mistakes). As for singletons, that class used to be singleton, but now Guice module manages Singleton instance

Comment: as long as it's not annotated with @Singleton, Guice won't treat it as one, afaik. Either way, being a singleton doesn't mean it can't have a public setter

Comment: Yes, I did not copy/paste the annotation of the class, sorry about that. It should be ok now?

Comment: How is the rotation done? Can the class that does the rotation get the `AccessVerifier` injected into it? BTW you’ll need `verifier` to be declared `volatile` for this to work consistently in a multi-threaded application.

Comment: @TimMoore the update is done in some mangled servlet-kind-of-code (pretty much custom). So I still have to implement injection there. I think I would be able to do it right away :(

Comment: On the other hand, the `secret` is stored in an object of the class `Settings`. But even if I would define `Provider<Settings>`, I would still need to detect changes made to that secret

Comment: It seems that the class that rotates the secret is important context for the question but is not currently included. Please add it.

Comment: Right now it is rather a manual task. Admin goes into settings HTTP page, inputs new secret, and submits. After validation, the secret gets into the `Settings` object (there is only one instance per app)

Comment: Can the code that puts the secret into the Settings object then call `setSecret` on the injected `AccessVerifier`?

Comment: It _could_ if that servlet would not be a total mess. I guess I could try injecting that `AccessVerifier` and then calling `setSecret` explicitly

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain why

```
App.getInjector().get(AccessVerifier.class).setSecret(...);
```

seems dirtier than

```
AccessVerifier.getInstance().setSecret(...);
```

These are both looking up the instance from somewhere and telling it to modify the secret.

If it's a Guice singleton, though, you can just @Inject it where you need it and call it directly:

```
class SecretResetter {
  private final AccessVerifier accessVerifier;

  @Inject
  SecretResetter(AccessVerifier accessVerifier) {
    this.accessVerifier = accessVerifier;
  }

  void resetSecret() {
    accessVerifier.setSecret(...);
  }
}
```